Having trouble combining two functions into one in React component
Here is example Image what I want to do I'm facing an issue while trying to combine two functions into one in my React component. Specifically, I'm working on a login page where I have two separate functions: one for changing the email input field and updating the eyes' image, and the other for toggling password visibility. Here's my code:

import { useState } from "react";
import face1 from "../assets/one.png";
import face2 from "../assets/two.png";
import face3 from "../assets/three.png";
import face4 from "../assets/four.png";
import face5 from "../assets/five.png";
import hide from "../assets/six.png";
import show from "../assets/seven.png";

const LoginPage = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
  const [eyesIndex, setEyesIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value !== "") {
      setEyesIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % 5);
      console.log(`Image changed to face${((eyesIndex + 1) % 5) + 1}`);
    }
  };

  const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
    setShowPassword(!showPassword);
  };

  const handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Backspace" && email === "") {
      setEyesIndex(0);
      console.log("Image changed to face1");
    }
  };

  const getPasswordImage = () => {
    return showPassword ? show : hide;
  };

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen bg-gray-100 flex flex-col items-center justify-center py-12 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div className="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full flex items-center flex-col sm:max-w-md">
        <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">
          Login
        </h2>
        <div className="home-page h-[10rem] w-[15rem] flex items-center">
          <img
            className="mx-auto h-16 w-auto"
            src={[face1, face2, face3, face4, face5][eyesIndex]}
            alt="Eyes"
          />
          <img
            className="mx-auto h-16 w-auto"
            src={getPasswordImage()}
            alt="Password"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="mt-8 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md">
        <div className="bg-white py-8 px-4 shadow sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
          <form className="space-y-6">
            <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="email"
                className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
              >
                Email address
              </label>
              <div className="mt-1 relative">
                <input
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  autoComplete="email"
                  onKeyDown={handleKeyPress}
                  required
                  value={email}
                  onChange={handleEmailChange}
                  placeholder="Email address"
                  className="pl-10 appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
                />
                <div className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 pr-3 flex items-center pointer-events-none">
                  <div className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400">
                    <i className="fa-regular fa-envelope"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div>
              <label
                htmlFor="password"
                className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
              >
                Email address
              </label>
              <div className="mt-1 relative">
                <input
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                  autoComplete="off"
                  placeholder="Password"
                  className="pl-10 appearance-none block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm placeholder-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
                />
                <div
                  className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 pr-3 flex items-center cursor-pointer"
                  onClick={togglePasswordVisibility}
                >
                  <div className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400">
                    {showPassword ? (
                      <i className="fa-regular fa-eye-slash"></i>
                    ) : (
                      <i className="fa-regular fa-eye"></i>
                    )}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
              <div className="flex items-center">
                <input
                  id="remember-me"
                  name="remember-me"
                  type="checkbox"
                  className="h-4 w-4 text-blue-600 focus:ring-blue-500 border-gray-300 rounded"
                />
                <label
                  htmlFor="remember-me"
                  className="ml-2 block text-sm text-gray-900"
                >
                  Remember me
                </label>
              </div>

              <div className="text-sm">
                <a
                  href="#"
                  className="font-medium text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-500"
                >
                  Forgot your password?
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
              >
                Log in
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;

Now, I want to merge the handleEmailChange and togglePasswordVisibility functions into one function to handle both the email change and password visibility toggle. However, I'm not sure how to combine these functionalities efficiently. When I tried to merge them, it caused some unexpected behavior.
Could someone please guide me on how to combine these two functions properly? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Why is it you want to combine these functions? They seem unrelated to me, so i'm not sure what the desired result would look like.

I'm not sure there is a valid reason to combine the functions, but here is how you can achieve the desired result:
const handleEmailandPassword = (e) => {
 if(e !== null){
    setEmail(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value !== "") {
      setEyesIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % 5);
      console.log(`Image changed to face${((eyesIndex + 1) % 5) + 1}`);
    }
 }else{
    setShowPassword(!showPassword);
 }

}
for the onChange event
onChange={(e) => handleEmailandPassword(e)}

for the OnClick event
onClick={() => handleEmailandPassword(null)}


I want to combine this two image container into one without changing its functionality  ==> 
<img
className="mx-auto h-16 w-auto"
src={[face1, face2, face3, face4, face5][eyesIndex]}
alt="Eyes"
/>


